# I need to extract working hour breaks out of a Time Statement List [C# | Vb.Net]

Tags: vb.net

I'm working on an API to import Time Statements (basically Excel sheets with working hours etc.) I have successfully read and saved the data in a BindingList(Of MyClass), but now I need to extract the time breaks in this list and put them into another separate list.

The problem is the hours need to be extracted in a specific way: I basically need the last column value of the first row, and I have to combine it with the penultimate column value of the second row to create a new record in the separate list.

The records in the separate list are differentiated by the Date.

I have tried to convert my BindingList to a DataTable to work with the row indices, but I have no idea how or where to start.

I hope I explained my problem well enough. I have also attached a screenshot with the two list structures and the way it should be handled.

I am looking forward to your ideas!

[image: Link to the Image Example]

Here is my breaks class, my timestamp class is basically the same without the First Name and Last Name property:

```
 Public Class BreaksMA
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

    Private _ID As String
    Public Property ID As String
        Get
            Return _ID
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _ID = value
            RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs("ID"))
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _Date As String
    Public Property DateX As String
        Get
            Return _Date
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _Date = value
            RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs("DateX"))
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _From As String
    Public Property From As String
        Get
            Return _From
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _From = value
            RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs("From"))
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _To As String
    Public Property ToX As String
        Get
            Return _To
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _To = value
            RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs("ToX"))
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
End Class
```

Here is my breaks list :

```
    Private _breakView As List(Of BreaksMA)
Public Property breakView As List(Of BreaksMA)
    Get
        Return _breakView
    End Get
    Set(value As List(Of BreaksMA))
        _breakView = value
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs("breakView"))
    End Set
End Property
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. The site is normally for people who have problems with their code, so we can help to fix it. But you haven't posted your approach, so it's hard to help.

Comment: Can you show us the definition of `MyClass`.  I'm about 99% sure you want to stay away from a `DataTable`.  Why a `BindingList<T>` and not just a `List<T>`

Comment: A `List<TimeStatement>` is sufficient for data processing and can be indexed. Assuming `TimeStatement` to be a class with ID, FistName, LastName, From, To properties.`BindingList` is for binding to an UI. `DataTable` is awkward.

Comment: Why is a datatable awkward? It's basically a 2D array, or a List<thingwithNproperties>, depending how you look at it

Comment: Does using a DataSet make sense in this case?

Comment: @Freeze: No.  DataTables and DataSets are used for extracting data from databases (and they are still a great way to do that if you are creating a desktop data editor.  There are much better ways of handling data

Comment: It is much easier to use your own custom class to store the times and the breaks than using a `DataTable`. Also if you are not using these classes to bind to an UI (to a `Form`), you don't need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Just use [Auto-Implemented Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/auto-implemented-properties).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution with no DataTables, DataSets or indices.

First, I strongly recommend that you work in DateTimes for the Dates and TimeSpans for your time stamps.  If you do it that way, you can do date and time math (notice that my solution has a read-only `Duration` property that is simply the difference between two times).

I do provide a way to get and set everything with strings, but the data is always stored in DateTimes and TimeSpans.

I don't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, it's not important to this solution.  You can add it back in.

When I started this (between meetings a few hours ago), your question was tagged C#, and you provided no code.  My C# is better than my VB - you can translate it back.  It's pretty obvious that you want VB - sorry, but I'm not doing this twice.  None of this is very complicated, it should be easy to transpile into VB by hand.

First I create two classes, one that represents your first grouping (BreaksMA in the code you eventually posted, `BreakTime` in my code) and the second that represents your second grouping (I called it `TimeStamp`).  Remember, I started this before you showed your code.
Feel free to refactor the names.

```
public class BreakTime
{
    public BreakTime(int id, string firstName, string lastName, DateTime date, TimeSpan fromTime, TimeSpan toTime)
    {
        Id = id;
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
        Date = date;
        FromTime = fromTime;
        ToTime = toTime;
    }

    public BreakTime(int id, string firstName, string lastName, string date, string fromTime, string toTime)
    {
        Id = id;
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
        DateString = date;
        FromTimeString = fromTime;
        ToTimeString = toTime;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Id}: {FirstName} {LastName}: {DateString} From: {FromTimeString}, To: {ToTimeString}";
    }

    private const string DateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy";
    private const string ToFromFormat = @"hh\:mm\:ss";
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public string DateString
    {
        get => Date.ToString(DateFormat);
        set => Date = DateTime.ParseExact(value, DateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }

    public TimeSpan FromTime { get; set; }

    public string FromTimeString
    {
        get => FromTime.ToString(ToFromFormat);
        set => FromTime = TimeSpan.ParseExact(value, ToFromFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }

    public TimeSpan ToTime { get; set; }

    public string ToTimeString
    {
        get => ToTime.ToString(ToFromFormat);
        set => ToTime = TimeSpan.ParseExact(value, ToFromFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
}
```

Note that you can get or set the date time-ish values either with the correct type (a DateTime or a TimeSpan) or a string.

The other type is basically the same idea, without the name information.  You might want to use inheritance for this, but I just used copy/paste:

```
public class TimeStamp
{
    public TimeStamp()
    {
        //everything gets set to default
    }

    public TimeStamp(int id, DateTime date, TimeSpan fromTime, TimeSpan toTime)
    {
        Id = id;
        Date = date;
        FromTime = fromTime;
        ToTime = toTime;
    }

    public TimeStamp(int id, string date, string fromTime, string toTime)
    {
        Id = id;
        DateString = date;
        FromTimeString = fromTime;
        ToTimeString = toTime;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Id}: {DateString} From: {FromTimeString}, To: {ToTimeString}, Duration: {Duration}";
    }

    private const string DateFormat = "MM.dd.yyyy";
    private const string ToFromFormat = @"hh\:mm\:ss";
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public string DateString
    {
        get => Date.ToString(DateFormat);
        set => Date = DateTime.ParseExact(value, DateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }

    public TimeSpan FromTime { get; set; }

    public string FromTimeString
    {
        get => FromTime.ToString(ToFromFormat);
        set => FromTime = TimeSpan.ParseExact(value, ToFromFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }

    public TimeSpan ToTime { get; set; }

    public string ToTimeString
    {
        get => ToTime.ToString(ToFromFormat);
        set => ToTime = TimeSpan.ParseExact(value, ToFromFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }

    public TimeSpan Duration => ToTime - FromTime;

    public string DurationString => Duration.ToString(ToFromFormat);
}
```

Other than the Name information, the only other significant difference is that the second class has a default constructor.

Note that I override `ToString` in each class.  This is very handy for debugging.

Now I initialize a list of the first type

> **Please**
> When you do something like this, include your data in some text format.  Half the effort in this answer involved retyping your data

```
public static List<BreakTime> Initialize()
{
    var returnedBreakTimes = new List<BreakTime>
    {
        new BreakTime(97, "John", "Snow", new DateTime(2021, 2, 1), new TimeSpan(12, 59, 0), new TimeSpan(16, 14, 0) ),
        new BreakTime(97, "John", "Snow", new DateTime(2021, 2, 1), new TimeSpan(16, 19, 0), new TimeSpan(16, 54, 0) ),
        new BreakTime(97, "John", "Snow", new DateTime(2021, 2, 1), new TimeSpan(17, 43, 0), new TimeSpan(19, 07, 0) ),
        new BreakTime(97, "John", "Snow", new DateTime(2021, 2, 1), new TimeSpan(19, 11, 0), new TimeSpan(20, 48, 0) ),
        new BreakTime(97, "John", "Snow", new DateTime(2021, 2, 1), new TimeSpan(20, 56, 0), new TimeSpan(22, 48, 0) ),

        //do the second day using strings (to test things out)
        new BreakTime(97, "John", "Snow", "02.02.2021", "12:56:00", "15:58:00" ),
        new BreakTime(97, "John", "Snow", "02.02.2021", "16:48:00", "18:36:00" ),
        new BreakTime(97, "John", "Snow", "02.02.2021", "18:40:00", "19:56:00" ),
        new BreakTime(97, "John", "Snow", "02.02.2021", "20:02:00", "21:45:00" ),
        new BreakTime(97, "John", "Snow", "02.02.2021", "21:49:00", "22:39:00" ),
    };

#if DEBUG
    foreach (var item in returnedBreakTimes)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(item);
    }
#endif
    return returnedBreakTimes;
}
```

Notice that I use both Date/Times and string to initialize things.  That way I can make sure that I'm interpreting the formats correctly, etc.

Finally, I get to the part you are interested in, parsing through the data on the left of your excel sheet and coming up with the data on the right.  To do this, I walk through the initial data and fabricate the final data by deciding if the day has changed, etc.  The code is not very complicated.

It looks like this:

```
public static List<TimeStamp> ParseFromBreakTimes(List<BreakTime> breakTimes)
{
    var listToReturn = new List<TimeStamp>();
    var currentDate = default(DateTime);
    var previousToTime = default(TimeSpan);

    foreach (var breakTime in breakTimes)
    {
        if (breakTime.Date != currentDate) //change in date
        {
            previousToTime = new TimeSpan();
        }

        if (previousToTime != default(TimeSpan))
        {
            listToReturn.Add(new TimeStamp(breakTime.Id, breakTime.Date, previousToTime, breakTime.FromTime));
        }

        previousToTime = breakTime.ToTime;
        currentDate = breakTime.Date;
    }

    return listToReturn;
}
```

To test it, I added this code to the `#if DEBUG` block in the `Initialize` routine:

```
var timestamps = ParseFromBreakTimes(returnedBreakTimes);
foreach (var item in timestamps)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(item);
}
```

When it runs, the output looks like this (note, I added the `Duration` as a test/demo):

```
97: John Snow: 01.02.2021 From: 12:59:00, To: 16:14:00
97: John Snow: 01.02.2021 From: 16:19:00, To: 16:54:00
97: John Snow: 01.02.2021 From: 17:43:00, To: 19:07:00
97: John Snow: 01.02.2021 From: 19:11:00, To: 20:48:00
97: John Snow: 01.02.2021 From: 20:56:00, To: 22:48:00
97: John Snow: 02.02.2021 From: 12:56:00, To: 15:58:00
97: John Snow: 02.02.2021 From: 16:48:00, To: 18:36:00
97: John Snow: 02.02.2021 From: 18:40:00, To: 19:56:00
97: John Snow: 02.02.2021 From: 20:02:00, To: 21:45:00
97: John Snow: 02.02.2021 From: 21:49:00, To: 22:39:00

97: 02.01.2021 From: 16:14:00, To: 16:19:00, Duration: 00:05:00
97: 02.01.2021 From: 16:54:00, To: 17:43:00, Duration: 00:49:00
97: 02.01.2021 From: 19:07:00, To: 19:11:00, Duration: 00:04:00
97: 02.01.2021 From: 20:48:00, To: 20:56:00, Duration: 00:08:00
97: 02.02.2021 From: 15:58:00, To: 16:48:00, Duration: 00:50:00
97: 02.02.2021 From: 18:36:00, To: 18:40:00, Duration: 00:04:00
97: 02.02.2021 From: 19:56:00, To: 20:02:00, Duration: 00:06:00
97: 02.02.2021 From: 21:45:00, To: 21:49:00, Duration: 00:04:00
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and effort! You are right about the correct usage of DateTimes and TimeSpans, I will definitly pay attention to this next time when I need them.